# why std::function is not executed

Tags: c++, function, bind, typedef

I am using std::bind to create a std::function type and typedef it, but its instance would not execute. Following is my code:

```
void func(int a, const std::string& b)
{
    std::cout << a << ", " << b << std::endl;
}
typedef std::function<void (int, const std::string&)> THE_FUNCTION;

THE_FUNCTION f = std::bind(func, 18, std::string("hello world"));

f; // no action at all
f(); // will not compile, term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
     // class does not define an 'operator()' or a user defined conversion operator 
     // to a pointer-to-function or reference-to-function that takes appropriate number 
     // of arguments
f.operator(); // will not compile, 'std::_Func_class<_Ret,int,const std::string &>::operator ()'
              // : non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
(&the_f)->operator(); // will not compile, 'std::_Func_class<_Ret,int,const std::string &>::operator ()': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
```

But if I do this, then the function will get executed:

```
auto g = std::bind(func, 3, "good morning")
g()
```

Comment: When you do `void (int, const std::string&)`, you are telling `std::funtion` that it's `operator()` will return `void` and have the parameters `int` and `const std::string&`.

Comment: But if this function is called, both the integer and the string will be printed out. In fact, there is nothing printed. I put the breaker pointer in the func, and it is not stopped there.

Comment: `f;` is a no-op; you aren't actually calling anything. `f()` attempts to call something - but as you noticed, it doesn't compile because you told `f` to expect two arguments but are passing none. `std::bind(func, 18, std::string("hello world"))` produces a callable taking no parameters; you probably meant to assign it to `std::function<void()>`

Comment: It's not executed because in all but one of the examples, it won't even *compile*. And the one that does compile is essentially an empty-statement no-op. In other words, `std::function<void()> f = std::bind(func, 18, std::string("hello world")));` then `f();` should work.

Comment: I need this typedef so it can be stored in a container. I tried 
`typedef std::function<void> THE_FUNCTION_2;
THE_FUNCTION_2 g = std::bind(func, 8, std::string("hehehe"));`
It will not compile.

Comment: Again, that would be `std::function<void()>`. Note the parentheses.

Comment: Thank you Igor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
typedef std::function<void (int, const std::string&)> THE_FUNCTION;
```

with:

```
typedef std::function<void ()> THE_FUNCTION;
```

and it will work.

L.E.: When you call bind, it means you have a function that "is very similar" with what you want, and fill the rest of the arguments that are not needed with some provided "values".

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind

Comment: This works. Thank you!
Now I have a further questions:
`void func(int a, const std::string& b) { std::cout << a << ", " << b << std::endl; }
typedef std::function<void ()> FUNCTION;
FUNCTION f = std::bind(func, 1, std::placeholders::_1);`
This does not compile.

Comment: because now you are using a placeholder. This means the signature you expect is std::function<void(const string&)> FUNCTION; This is the reason we use bind in the first place, because we can create custom function pointers for existing functions, providing some values and some "expected parameters via placeholders"